# C++ ignore alphabetical characters when reading input from a file

Tags: c++, io, io-redirection

I have a program that takes an input stream from a text file, which contains positive integers, delimited by spaces. The file contains only numbers and one instance of `abc` which my program should ignore before continuing to read data from the file.

this is my code and it does not work

```
    int line;
    in >> line;
    in.ignore(1, 'abc');
    in.clear();
```

could someone specify what the problem is? essentially, I want to discard the alpha input, clear cin and continue to read from file but I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

I get three parts from the input stream, and put the useful parts into a `stringstream` and read from it

```
int part1, part2;
std::string abc;
in >> part1 >> abc >> part2;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << part1 << part2;
int line;
ss >> line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitely ignore any alphabetical character this way:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

std::istream& read_number(std::istream& is, int& number) {
    auto& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(is.getloc());
    while(ctype.is(std::ctype_base::alpha, is.peek())) is.ignore(1);
    return is >> number;
}

int main() {
  using std::string;
  using std::cin;
  using std::locale;

  int number;
  while(read_number(std::cin, number)) {
    std::cout << number << ' ';
  }
}
```

For input like "452abc def 23 11 -233b" this will produce "452 23 11 -233".